# how do I make this run constructor work right?

Tags: java, swing

[I have the following code](http://pastebin.com/bRS0zTVX):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TTT extends JFrame implements ActionListener { //DO NOT TOUCH!!!

    //makes the array for the buttons
    JButton spots[ ] = new JButton[ 9];
    //keeps track of who's turn it is
    int turn = 0;
    //lets it go again
    boolean go = true;
    //gets the images for the X's and O's
    ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("x.PNG");
    ImageIcon blue = new ImageIcon("o.PNG");
    ImageIcon blank = new ImageIcon("blank.PNG");

    public static void main (String []args ) {
        TTT frame = new TTT(); //DO NOT TOUCH!!!
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TTT( ) { //DO NOT TOUCH!!!
        //set the frame default properties
        setTitle ("Tic Tac Toe");
        setSize ( 308, 308 );
        setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        setResizable(false);
        //register 'Exit upon closing' as a default close operation
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        changeBkColor( );
    }

    private void changeBkColor() {
        while (go) {
            //declares some variables that we will use later
            int newLine = 0;
            int lineCount = 0;
            //change background color to white
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            //puts the buttons on the screen
            for (int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++) {
                //make it first appear as a blank image
                spots[ i] = new JButton (blank);
                //checks if it needs a new row
                if (i == 3 || i == 6) {
                    newLine++;
                    lineCount = 0;
                }
                //sets the positions of the buttons
                spots[ i].setBounds(lineCount*100, newLine*100, 100, 100);
                //add it to the container
                contentPane.add(spots[ i]);
                spots[ i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
/*** Line 62 ***/       public void run() { 
                            //check button pressed
                            for (int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++) {
                                if(e.getSource()==spots[ i]) {
                                    //check turn
                                    if (turn%2==0) {
                                        spots[ i].setIcon(red);
                                    } else {
                                    spots[ i].setIcon(blue);
                                    }
                                    //disable the button so it can't be re-pressed
                                    spots[ i].removeActionListener(this);
                                }
                            }
                            turn++;
                            //checks for wins
                            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                if (spots[ i].getIcon()==red &&                //checks for verticle x win
                                    spots[ i+3].getIcon()==red &&
                                    spots[ i+6].getIcon()==red) {
                                        int again1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "X Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                        if (again1 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                            go = true;
                                        } if (again1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                            go = false;
                                        }
                                }else if (spots[ i].getIcon()==blue &&     //checks for verticle o win
                                            spots[ i+3].getIcon()==blue &&
                                            spots[ i+6].getIcon()==blue) {
                                                int again2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "O Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                                if (again2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                                    go = true;
                                                } if (again2 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                                    go = false;
                                                }
                                }else if (spots[ i*3].getIcon()==red &&    //checks for horizontal x win
                                            spots[ (i*3)+1].getIcon()==red &&
                                            spots[ (i*3)+2].getIcon()==red) {
                                                int again3 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "X Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                                if (again3 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                                    go = true;
                                                } if (again3 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                                    go = false;
                                                }
                                }else if (spots[ i*3].getIcon()==blue &&   //checks for horizontal o win
                                            spots[ (i*3)+1].getIcon()==blue &&
                                            spots[ (i*3)+2].getIcon()==blue) {
                                                int again4 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "O Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                                if (again4 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                                    go = true;
                                                } if (again4 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                                    go = false;
                                                }
                                }else if (spots[ i].getIcon()==red &&      //checks for diagnol x win
                                            spots[ 4].getIcon()==red &&
                                            spots[ 8-i].getIcon()==red) {
                                                int again5 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "X Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                                if (again5 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                                    go = true;
                                                } if (again5 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                                    go = false;
                                                }
                                }else if (spots[ i].getIcon()==blue &&    //checks for diagnol o win
                                            spots[ 4].getIcon()==blue &&
                                            spots[ 8-i].getIcon()==blue) {
                                                int again6 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "O Wins! Do you want to play again?", "Play again?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                                                if (again6 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                                    go = true;
                                                } if (again6 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Okay then. Bye!");
                                                    go = false;
                                                }
                                }
                            }
                            lineCount++;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } if (!go) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

my compile hates line 62 - public void run() { - and I need help fixing it. I copied and pasted the line for an already-working program, so I don't know how it doesn't work. 
*EDIT*
sorry guys, here's my errors:

```
TTT.java:62: error: illegal start of expression
                    public void run() {
                    ^
TTT.java:62: error: illegal start of expression
                    public void run() {
                           ^
TTT.java:62: error: ';' expected
                    public void run() {
                                   ^
```

Comment: -1 for blind copying and pasting.  Your error is pretty fundamental, so I don't think you'll get much help asking questions like this.  I recommend finding a good Java book or tutorial first.

Comment: What's the compiler error? For future reference you don't need a pastebin for code. Just include the code and any relevant error messages in the question. @Maxpm: Actually I don't mind copying-and-pasting if the OP included the compiler error in the process. Unfortunately that's not the case here.

Comment: Why you think this should work? Just because you copy it from a working code?

Comment: @Insilico : It is *very* obvious that we can not write a method inside a method without an anonymous class. In OP's case he forgot to create new Thread or Runnable class to write run method in.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Java isn't my primary programming language, so what's blindingly obvious to you isn't obvious to me (a person who primarily uses C++; I have 1393 upvotes for C++ answers vs. 77 upvotes for Java answers as of this time of writing). In C++11 you can in fact have functions defined within functions ([lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions)), and I haven't switched to "Java mode" when reading the OP's question.

Comment: @Insilico: that's why OP is suggested to read Java books and tutorials.

Comment: @Harry Joy: And I completely agree with the suggestion. But I don't see why telling *me* that I can't write a method inside a method without an anonymous class will help *the OP* with the question.

Comment: @Insilico : That was in response to your query: "What's the compiler error?", and also indirectly giving hint to OP that he/she needs to create an anonymous class to solve the error. I have also mentioned names of class that OP should try to solve the problem.

Comment: @Harry Joy: Yes, I appreciate you answering that, but it was directed towards the OP, hopefully nudging the OP towards a way to improve the question.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have defined a method within another method declaration, namely `run()` within `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`.

This is not allowed in Java.

It also appears that you have a misunderstanding about the declaration of `static void run()` this is not a constructor; it is a method declaration with a return type of void.

Answer (score 1):

changeBkColor is an infinite loop so after the constructor is called frame.setVisible(true) is never called. Might be an issue.